# How to have single window with different ui classes with PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Can I use different classes of UI that will display on a certain part of the window but still use a single window? It will be like `<div></div>` elements on HTML. I tried like shown below, but the `self.header` the label did not show up after pressing `self.some_button`

MainUi.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class UserInterface(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # As Main Window, every widget will always be displayed

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("WindowTitle")
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        self.main_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.main_title.setText("Some text")

        self.some_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.some_button.move(20, 20)
        self.some_button.setText("Some Button")
        self.some_button.adjustSize()

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class AboutPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # As widget class, will be shown on a certain part of the main window

    def __init__(self, parent=None, person=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.header = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.header.move(40, 0)
        self.header.setText(f"Some header {person}")

        self.show()
```

MainControl.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from MainUi import *

class ControlMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_ui = UserInterface()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self)

        self.main_ui.some_button.clicked.connect(self.draw_about)

    def draw_about(self):
        self.about_ui = AboutPerson(self.main_ui, 'John')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    program = ControlMainWindow()
    program.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget will be displayed in a window if it is a child of the window or a child of a widget already displayed in the window. "self.about_ui" if it is shown in the window since it is a child of the window but "header" not since it is not a child of either the window or "self.about_ui". One solution is to pass the parent:

```
self.header = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
```